# Magento 2 add telephone number in to the customer account creation form

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-address

I want to add **telephone number into customer registration form**. I get the telephone number field out of `if($this->getShowAddressFields())` section and put it outside. Then the field displayed in front end form. But after I submit to create **the customer telephone number it is not saving**.

Anyone can give me a suggestion?

Comment: Paste code what u have tried with full file path

Comment: You should enable both address field during registration or you can create a customer attribute to save under customer scope.